# get Common rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table :

```
     Subject_ID StudyPlan_ID   
       271            2   
       279            2  
       276            2  
       279            8 
       271            8   
       267            9   
       279            9
```

I want to find the common `Subject_ID` between `StudyPlan_ID` so it's `279` using SqlServer 2008
So please any help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you mean find the Subject_ID that is linked to every StudyPlan_ID.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE(Subject_ID int, StudyPlan_ID int)
INSERT INTO @Data
    VALUES
        (271, 2),
        (279, 2),
        (276, 2),
        (279, 8),
        (271, 8), 
        (267, 9),
        (279, 9)

SELECT Subject_ID
FROM @Data AS a
GROUP BY Subject_ID
HAVING COUNT(Distinct StudyPlan_ID) = (SELECT COUNT(Distinct StudyPlan_ID) FROM @Data)
```